# advice needed for SQL query

Tags: sql

Can some one help to provide the SQL query should be used to pull out the "columna" value which has max number "columnb" value as "Active". Means in columnb there is a value "Active" , I want to pull the columna value which has max of value Active n columnb.

I am looking output to be columna = M1 and Count = 4

```
columna     columnb
M1          Active
M1          Active
M1          Active
M1          Active
M2          failed
M2          failed
M2          failed
M3          pending
M3          pending
M3          pending
```

Comment: Question is unclear, please provide what you've tried, example data, and expected results.

Comment: What are some typical values of columnB?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Syntax for getting max row could be different.

Comment: i think this will do; `select columna, count(columnb) as count from <table> Where columnb = 'Active' Group by columna`...I think the whole thing about max of value is out of context here

Answer (score 1):

The results you request would be produced by:

```
SELECT columna,COUNT(*)
FROM Table
WHERE columnb = 'Active'
GROUP BY columna
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT top 1 columna,COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM Table1
WHERE columnb = 'Active'
GROUP BY columna
order by cnt desc
```

**[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a81e/4)**

Comment: let me try this out and come  back.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT columna,count(*) FROM TABLE_NAME where columnb = "Active" GROUP BY columna
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is slightly different between RDMBS-es, but logic remains. Filter your rows based on `columnb`, group them by `columna`, order them on `count(*)` and select top 1

SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 columna, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM YourTable
WHERE columnb = 'Active'
GROUP BY columna
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc85c/2)

MySQL:

```
SELECT columna, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM YourTable
WHERE columnb = 'Active'
GROUP BY columna
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fda87/1)